# Javascript/jQuery array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, javascript-objects, iscroll

Is it possible to create an array of objects? I'm wondering this because I'm developing an iPad website that has a bunch of fields that will need to be scrollable on the iPad.

Of course iPad/Safari had to go and make things difficult and not use the overflow-x/y option to allow scrollbars. So, what I'm hoping to do is create an array of iScroll objects because there's a large amount of things that need to be created and I would rather not do:

```
var myScroll = new iScroll();
var myScroll = new iScroll();
```

Etc.

What I would hope to do is have some sort of loop like:

```
var arrayOfObjects=new Array();
for(var i=0; i < numFields; i++)
{
   var temp = new iScroll();
   arrayOfObjects.push(temp);
}
```

So, is something like this doable?

Comment: Yes it's possible and your code should work in achieving that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code you posted would work fine. A few nitpicks:

```
var arrayOfObjects = []; // use this syntax instead of "new array"
for (var i = 0; i < numFields; i++) {
   arrayOfObjects.push(new iScroll()); // no reason for a temp var
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
var arrayOfObjects=new Array();
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
   var temp = new Object();
   arrayOfObjects.push(temp);
}
```

The above code produces: [Object, Object, Object, ... ] for the value of arrayOfObjects

Comment: Excellent! I was hoping it would work, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: So this answer is just a reiteration of the OP's code but with `Object` instead of `iScroll`?

Comment: A good way to test out your script is by hitting Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome and pasting the code into the console window. It's a handy JS REPL. At least that's what I did.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, I'm assuming iScroll is an object, but without the implementation of iScroll I just used Object as a substitute.

Answer (score 1):

What you want, can be achieved by [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) like this:

```
var arrayObjects = $.map(Array(numFields), function(){ return new iScroll(); } );
```

Comment: And here I was thinking (facetiously) that there wasn't enough jQuery in the other answers. +1 though, I hadn't thought to use `.map()` for that sort of thing before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as far as im away you can do this.

I would usually say:

```
var myArray = []
var myArray[0] = new iScroll();
var myArray[1] = new iScroll();
var myArray[2] = new iScroll();
var myArray[3] = new iScroll();
```

But doing it in a loop should work the same :)

Comment: You could say `var myArray = [new iScroll(),new iScroll(),new iScroll(),new iScroll()]`

Comment: Yes, good point, just wanted to keep it simple though i will update :)

Comment: I don't think the OP needs it this simplified given that he or she came up with the correct syntax for a loop implementation without our help. (Especially when a loop is actually fewer lines of code as soon as you have three or more elements...)